# Remote management of OpenWrt routers without port forwarding

Tags: linux, networking, openwrt

Is there a way to remote manage my OpenWrt (v15) routers?

The routers are installed by clients which cannot port forward.
I was thinking of an VPN or a ssh tunnel but with the many routers I don't think it is a efficient solution. So I am searching for a way (open source) to remote manage my routers without *port forwarding*.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. You may try to [edit] your post adding some information more about the specific model/software version.

Comment: First idea: Activate `sshd` (`dropbear`) on all OpenWRT routers when you install them, generate ssh-key, put key on all routers. Then access from Internet via `ssh`, script if necessary. Google also finds quite a few approaches and packages to remote manage them.

Comment: @dirkt Hi, but to access the routers via ssh port forwarding is needed? And that is not possible in this case. I didnt find anything on google except some companies who provide it but i am searching for a open source solution.

Comment: You can access your router via SSH without port forwarding, unless the router is behind a NAT (like carrier-grade NAT, for example). I guess that's what you have in mind but you're not being very clear about it.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes it is standard here in the Netherlands EDIT: i want to access the router via WAN. Maybe that clears it up

Comment: I would go with VPN, I've been using OpenVPN on OpenWRT for few years. You'll need one machine with public IP (or forwarded port) to act as a VPN server. With proper config every newly-added router will stress your server a *little* more, but not the other routers. Encryption might be a burden to slow routers but it should hardly ever be a problem because you don't need much to *manage* a router; also a router doesn't have to be super-realtime-responsive while you do your managing. You can even start your server only when you need it (wait a minute until your routers register, then manage).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks! Will go that way then

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do ssh if you add this in firewall file,

```
config redirect
    option src 'wan'
    option src_dport '22'
    option dest 'lan'
    option dest_port '22'
    option proto 'tcp'
```

You can set your destination port from 22 to anything you want.